# Make a users list like instagram

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, lumen

please help.. 
I have 2 tables
Current user_id = 3
Users Table:

```
|  user_id  |      email       |   name   |
-------------------------------------------
|     1     |   one@gmail.com  |  ridwan  |
|     2     |   two@gmail.com  |   budi   |
|     3     |   six@gmail.com  |  stevan  |
|     4     |   ten@gmail.com  |  agung   |
```

Relations Table [ user_id and follower_id are related to Users Table ]

```
|  relation_id  | user_id | follower_id | 
----------------------------------------- 
|       1       |    1    |      3      | 
|       2       |    2    |      3      |
```

i want to get the list of the user, but if i already have relation with a user, it will give me a status 'following', just like instagram, maybe look like this

```
{
    user_id : 1,
    name    : ridwan,
    status  : following
},
{
    user_id : 2,
    name    : budi,
    status  : following
},
{
    user_id : 4,
    name    : agung,
    status  : not following
}
```

how can i do that in laravel?

thank you..

Comment: Maybe [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) can help you. You have to define the relationships in your models and then your can retrieve them by making the right [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources).

Answer (score 0):

In your Relations model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then, in your controller (where you want to get this list), you just need to use Eloquent or Query Builder to get what you want (with eager loading, it's always better) :

```
//get all users related to your_current_user
$relations = Relation::where('follower_id', your_current_user_id)->with('user')->get();
```

Finally, you just have to make manipulate your data like you want, for example :

```
foreach($relations as $relation){
    $relation->user->name; //get the name of the related user
}
```

Take a look at [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.. finally I use sql case, i was only confusing about how to get the data with 'following' status

here is the code:

```
DB::table('users')->leftjoin('relationships', 'users.user_id', '=', 'relationships.user_id')->select('users.user_id','users.status as user_type','users.email','users.display_name','users.profile_image',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN relationships.follower_id = ' . $user_id . ' THEN "Following" ELSE "Not Following" END) AS status'))->orderBy('user_id','asc')->where('users.user_id','!=',$user_id)->get();
```